# Corrupted installation of ubuntu 15.10

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, suspend, recovery-mode

While installing upgrades (I know, the worst moment) my computer went into suspend mode. I thought I had disabled any screensaver, or similar. Evidently I was wrong and now I can access my user only via terminal and since I'm not really an expert I'm getting confused on what to do and how to do it.

My question is: is there a way I can recover this installation without losing all my data and preferences (limited to what the original possibilities upgrading the version of ubuntu were)? I suppose so but as I said, given my poor knowledge, there's the risk I even get to make the situation worse.

I tried recovery mode but what happens is that I end up with a "request" to log in, but only on the terminal. Please I need help, if you are able to help me, try to be as specific and as "elementary" as possible...Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, thanks. I did what you suggested, sadly everything worked almost until the end; in fact when the installation was over, a message concerning the impossibility of restoring some packages appeared, it said to restart the system and possibly the problem would have been fixed with this procedure. So I did, however, after i removed the installation medium and pressed enter nothing happened for about a hour, the screen was black. I repeated all the installation, now I get this message: end kernel panic..Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)...Should I open another question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any other working computer, go ahead and download the Ubuntu version you have installed. Burn it to a disk and boot it up. When it prompts you to try it or install it, click install it and it will detect your Ubuntu version, giving you a bunch of options. You're gonna wanna go ahead and choose "Reinstall Ubuntu XX.xx". This won't delete any personal files, as the image shows: [image: Installation Window]